# Prevent drawer_layout from slidein by touch

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a drawer layout working well, but I want to disable "open by dragging from left of screen to right", how can I do it?

current layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment 
                  class="net.MyFragment"
                  android:id="@+id/fragment_reading"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </fragment>
    </FrameLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111"
            android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
            />

    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Set it in LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED state during creation, and open/close it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

where `mDrawerLayout` is your `DrawerLayout`

This will lock your drawer

And on your button click you can open and close it using

```
if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList))
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
else
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

where `mDrawerList` is your `ExpandableListView`